# pythonのOpenCVで画像歪み補正

Tags: python, opencv

PythonのOpenCVで画像のゆがみ補正を行いたいのですが、下記のようなコードで撮影したチェスボードから
ゆがみ係数を求めるというのはわかったのですが、Webサービスなどでユーザーのアップロードした画像のゆがみを補正する場合など（画像サイズも不規則）はこの係数はどう求めたらいいのでしょうか？

findChessboardCornersやfindCirclesGridを使用しないでゆがみを補正する方法があればご教授頂ければと思います。

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import glob

    fileName = "chess.jpg"
    imagePath = "./" + fileName

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ChessboardPatternSize = (9, 7)

    height, width = image.shape[:2]

    objPoints = [] # 3d point
    imgPoints = [] # 2d points 

    # termination criteria
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 0, 0.1)

    objp = np.zeros( (np.prod(ChessboardPatternSize), 3), np.float32 )
    objp[:,:2] = np.indices(ChessboardPatternSize).T.reshape(-1, 2)
    objp *= 1

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(grayImage, ChessboardPatternSize)

    if ret == True:

      corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(grayImage, corners, (11, 11), (-1,-1), criteria)

      objPoints.append(objp)
      imgPoints.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))

      print objPoints
      print imgPoints
      np.save('objPoints.npy', objPoints)
      np.save('imgPoints.npy', imgPoints)
```

Comment: 「findXxxxを使用しないでゆがみを補正」という部分の要件が不明瞭なのですが、その条件下での「ゆがみ」は何(どういう状態)で、どのように補正(あるべき結果)したいのでしょう？現状の要望を端的に解釈すると「人間が見たときにいい感じに映像を加工したい」という曖昧で実現不可能な要件に見受けられます…

Comment: 失礼致しました。
状態としては、スマートフォンに広角レンズを着用しアップロードされた画像の歪みを補正したいです。
撮影に使用されたスマートフォンもバラバラなので、findXxxxなどで歪み係数を求めることが不可能と思い質問させていただきました。

Comment: 具体的に歪んだ写真を提示してもらえますか？面白い問題だと思うのでやってみます！

Answer (score 1):

> findChessboardCornersやfindCirclesGridを使用しないでゆがみを補正する方法があれば
>   スマートフォンに広角レンズを着用しアップロードされた画像の歪みを補正したいです。

実現不可能です。未知の「ゆがみ」をキャリブレーションなしに画像補正することは出来ません。

与えられた前提条件だけでは「ゆがみ」をモデル化することができず、復元したいオリジナルの映像、すなわち逆変換を定義できません。チェッカーボード等を用いたキャリブレーションでは、撮像系のゆがみモデル定式化を仮定し、そのモデルのパラメータを逆推定することで補正を行っています。そのような補助データなしに本来の映像を復元することは（人間の"勘"をのぞけば）実現不可能です。

---

ちょっとだけ補足：スマートフォンに取り付ける広角レンズの光学特性と、マウンタなどで取り付け位置を固定させることができるならば、事前キャリブレーションしたパラメータを記録しておき、全ての映像を同パラメータで補正するという手段が取れます。（カメラ・レンズのメーカはこれ相当のことをやっているはずです）

Comment: やはりそうですよね、ありがとうございます！

Comment: なるほど。。！ご丁寧にありがとうございます！
スマートフォンの機種がバラバラでも適応できるものなのでしょうか。。？

Comment: スマートフォンと広角レンズを、事前パラメータ方式でサポートするのはやはり無理です（各ユーザがどんなレンズを使ったか、どう取り付けたかを事前に全て把握出来ないですよね？）。結局はその端末でチェッカーボードなどを撮影してキャリブレーション・パラメータを算出しないといけませんから。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
自分も難しいと思っていたのですが、ただ自分が無知なだけかと思い質問させていただきました。
ご丁寧にありがとうございました！